# how to get Facebook page using FQL, given a company's website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a list companies and their websites (for example: http://www.target.com).  I'd like to programatically determine their pages on Facebook (http://www.facebook.com/target).  How can I use FQL to get the Facebook username, page_id, or actual Facebook page_url from a company's website?

I've searched for a query or combination of queries that can get me there, but no avail.  The obvious query

```
SELECT page_id, page_url FROM page WHERE website = 'http://www.target.com'
```

fails because website is not an indexed field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This FQL will start getting any `website` containing the string passed to`CONTAINS` function.  After getting a list of websites, the condition `website = "www.google.com"` will filter the list of websites and get exactly the page info required.

This is the FQL you need to execute:

```
Select page_id,page_url,website from page where website = "www.google.com" 
And username in (select username,website from page where contains("google.com"))
```

**Note** : Use the domain and domain TLD only like `google.com` or only `google` inside `CONTAINS` function

But if you executed this FQL

```
select page_id,page_url,website from page where contains("www.google.com")
```

You will notice that you will get a big list of output that don't meet the search criteria..

Regards,,,

Comment: Thanks - this looks promising.  Field 'website' is not an indexed field in table 'page', so FQL threw an error when I used it as a query condition (see code in my original post).  Is it the addition of a second indexed field in the condition that makes this acceptable to FQL?

Comment: I've noticed that the website field may or may not contain the scheme (http, https) and may or may not contain a subdomain (www, etc.) using `strpos(website, "google.com") >= 0` is a good filter rather than `website = "www.google.com"`

Comment: Welcome my friend and thanks for the addition of using the function - strpos. GOOOD LUCK

Answer (score 1):

Facebook limits what is searchable. I believe the best you can do is to search for "Target.com" in all Facebook pages.

```
SELECT page_id, page_url FROM page WHERE CONTAINS('target.com')
```